# what's the maximum number of simultaneous java socket connections in the cluster?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, cluster, spark

we work within a cluster of 1 gb/s of bandwidth, we use java sockets to perform some data transfer between the cluster's nodes like broadcast and shuffle (nodes of the cluster exchange data) in the cluster, in the instant t we may have multiple simultaneous transfers.
[image: here is an illustration]
we want to get the maximum number of simultaneous connections so we can fix the number and manage it by giving parts of the network to every connection

what is the maximum number of open socket connections in the cluster to maximize the data processing?

Comment: Would this not be also limited by the operating system(s) you are using?

Comment: we suppose that it's not

Comment: we actually want to determine the max number of connections for example 500 connections and if for example two transfers occur in the network and the first one requires only 300 connections so we give the remaining amount of connections to the other one.